# SQL Multiple Filter - Optimal Way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

**How do you implement this simple scenario with the least possible cost (SQL) ?**

(*implement a stored procedure supporting all combinations of the filters applied.*)

```
Table

    name | dateOfbirth | phone | email
     N1  | 01-01-1992  | P1    | E1
     N2  | 12-08-1976  | P2    | E2
     N3  | 09-11-1989  | P3    | E3
     N4  | 04-06-1991  | P4    | E4

    Filter 
    [x] Name
    [x] dateOfbirth 
    [x] phone
    [x] email
```

After seeing SQL queries and filters implemented  for many years and in many ways.

I think it's high time for me to refresh.

### References

1. http://bit.ly/RYHzaF
2. http://bit.ly/QyX103

> Mark / Correct this question if found as duplicate

Comment: The definitive article on the topic. [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever I do optional filters, I choose some data that will represent all data, and then use something like this:

```
SELECT name, dateOfbirth, phone, email
  FROM Table
 WHERE (@a_name  = '' or name = @a_name)
   AND (@a_date  = '1900-01-01' or dateOfbirth = @a_date)
   AND (@a_phone = '' or phone = @a_phone)
   AND (@a_email = '' or email = @a_email)
```

Comment: Do you know how to transform this to knexJS?

Answer (score 4):

Will this be any help? `@f1,...,@f4 are filters and assuming null if filtering not needed`

```
SELECT name, dateOfBirth, phone, email
FROM YourTable
WHERE name = ISNULL(@f1,name) AND dateOfBirth = ISNULL(@f2,dateOfBirth) AND
      phone = ISNULL(@f3,phone) AND email = ISNULL(@f4,email)
```